# Custom cursor for entire WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, cursor

I am trying to get a custom cursor for my WPF application. I already have the .cur file in the Resources. In the xaml, I mentioned the resource dictionary something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <FrameworkElement x:Key="KinectCursor" Cursor="Resources/KinectCursor.cur"/>
            <FrameworkElement x:Key="KinectCursor16" Cursor="Resources/KinectCursor16.cur"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
```

In the code-behind, I tried to the set the Mouse.OverrdeCursor property to this cursor but it is throwing exceptions.

```
 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Mouse.OverrideCursor = this.Resources["KinectCursor"].Cursor;
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = ((FrameworkElement)this.Resources["KinectCursor"]).Cursor;
            //DisplayArea.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        }
```

Exception Message:

```
XAMLParseException occured.
'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' 
threw an exception.' Line number '7' and line position '14'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurrs sometimes if you pass a wrong relative icon path. Try to do it like this:

```
...
<FrameworkElement 
    x:Key="KinectCursor" 
    Cursor="pack://application:,,,/(AssemblyName);component/Resources/KinectCursor.cur"/>
...
```